# Formula that retrieves the cell value of another cell the row below it

Tags: excel

I've got a dataset which has a blank row and a file name in the row below it repeating for the whole sheet multiple times. Each file name is different and what im wanting to capture in the currently blank row is the cell value of the cell below it i.e the filename with a formula.

Im not very proficient in excel sheets but feel this is something simple?
This provides me what i need but it is not dynamic.
="FILENAME IS" & A2

I need a formula i can copy across all the blank rows which will do something like ="FILENAME IS" & A:ROW()+1

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `="FILENAME IS" & A2` should work. If you copy/paste formula into row 3, it will get get converted to `="FILENAME IS" & A4` and so on.. What do you mean with dynamic?

Comment: Please add an example of the sheet with expected output

Comment: Oh wow didnt think it was going to keep appending like that thought it just stayed A2 for all the rows. Thanks very much!

Comment: @DanielOtto This is the normal way Excel works :) **I strongly suggest** to read about [Switch between relative, absolute, and mixed references](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/switch-between-relative-absolute-and-mixed-references-dfec08cd-ae65-4f56-839e-5f0d8d0baca9?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Answer (score 2):

Obviously my lack of knowledge but thanks kto Foxfire And Burns And Burns ;

Simply copying ="FILENAME IS" & A2  into the blank rows did the job as A2 became A4 and A6 and so on when copied.

Comment: FYI, if you DO want it to stay the same and not increment the row number or column letter for you when pasting, you can put a $ before either the letter ($A2), or number (A$2), or both ($A$2) and it will not change it.